# Unclear instructions in sprouting jar

Tags: sprouting

Sorry if the question sounds stupid. I have never done sprouting before, saw this jar on sale and bought it. I read a few short [guides](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-grow-sprouts-in-a-jar-2540007), but the instructions within the jar are a bit different to usual (no initial seed soaking for 1-2hs).

[image]

It is quite specific in the water temperature aspect. The sun, if it can't be seen properly, is a HAPPY sun, so I guess it means sunlight, but elsewhere I have read usually states to put it on a dark place.

Finally, inside the rectangle, I can see for 5 days, and a 2 - 3x, which my common sense tells me 2 or 3 times (some sites state 2-4, I guess it does not matter much), but the calendar marks are a bit misleading to me. The 3 and 2 marks are there to state random drains? OR 2 x 3s, in the sense of 2 times (days), 3 drains, the rest, 2?

For consumption, I see that Friday and Saturday (fifth and seventh day) are OK, but on the sixth day? After that, put somewhere 4h before consumption, outside the jar, and they can be stored (INSIDE A JAR? It does not seem the same type of jar due to the lid). My guess is that everything should be put somewhere for 4h (ventilation I guess), and then either eaten or stored, without another 4hs next time?

So in the end?

1. Put seeds, warm water, and drain
2. Repeat adding water and draining, 2 to 3 times for 5 days (??)
3. "Collect" in the following 2 days (??)
4. Collect = put outside jar for 4 hours, then eat or storen normally for up to 1 week (?)

Comment: Just go with some nice normal instructions from a reputable source, rather than worrying about vague graphical instructions packed with the jar. The jar is not particularly special.

Comment: Sounds about right... Thanks! @Ecnerwal